# Extract faces from video using AWS Rekognition

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-rekognition

With AWS Rekognition I was able to get faces detected in a mp4 video with the following nodejs,

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");                                                                                              
AWS.config.update({                                                                                                        
  region: "us-east-1"                                                                                                      
});                                                                                                                        

var rekognition = new AWS.Rekognition();                                                                                   



var params = {                                                                                                             
  Video: { /* required */                                                                                                  
    S3Object: {                                                                                                            
      Bucket: 'videobucket',                                                                                          
      Name: 'testvideo.mp4'                                                                                                
    }                                                                                                                      
  },                                                                                                                       
  FaceAttributes: "ALL",                                                                                                   
  NotificationChannel: {                                                                                                   
    RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/xxx', /* required */                                                     
    SNSTopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxx:alerts' /* required */                                                
  }                                                                                                                        
};                                                                                                                         
rekognition.startFaceDetection(params, function(err, data) {                                                               
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred                                                               
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response                                                             
});
```

And was able to get the results with the following cli,

> aws rekognition get-face-detection --job-id   xxxxxxx

and outputs the faces in the following json format,

```
{                                                                                                                          
    "Faces": [                                                                                                             
        {                                                                                                                  
            "Timestamp": 0,                                                                                                
            "Face": {                                                                                                      
                "BoundingBox": {                                                                                           
                    "Width": 0.029999999329447746,                                                                         
                    "Top": 0.2588889002799988,                                                                             
                    "Left": 0.29374998807907104,                                                                           
                    "Height": 0.052222222089767456                                                                         
                },                                                                                                         
                "Landmarks": [                                                                                             
                    {                                                                                                      
                        "Y": 0.28277161717414856,                                                                          
                        "X": 0.3052537739276886,                                                                           
                        "Type": "eyeLeft"                                                                                  
                    },                                                                                                     
                    {                                                                                                      
                        "Y": 0.27957838773727417,                                                                          
                        "X": 0.3085327744483948,                                                                           
                        "Type": "eyeRight"
```

How to extract those faces as images and dump them in an s3 bucket?

Thanks

Comment: How did you solve your problem?

Comment: Not yet solved.

Comment: Why do not you just take the frame at the timestamp provided by aws, crop the region (again, provided by aws) and dump faces one by one?

Comment: How to select a frame and crop the image out of it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps followed to extract the faces. With the output from AWS rekognition, create a shell script output to extract the faces using ffmpeg. Added extra padding to the face to get hair, chin and side ears. You can adjust based on your needs.

```
var faces = require('./output1.json');                                                                                     

var oldtimestamp = -1;                                                                                                     
var sequence = 1;                                                                                                          



faces.Faces.forEach(function(element) {                                                                                    
    var size = element.Face.BoundingBox;                                                                                   
    var vheight = 576;                                                                                                     
    var vwidth = 720;                                                                                                      
    size.Width = parseInt(size.Width * 1.25 *  vwidth);                                                                    
    size.Left = parseInt(size.Left * vwidth);                                                                              
    size.Top = parseInt(size.Top * 0.5  * vheight)  ;                                                                      
    size.Height = parseInt(size.Height * 1.75 * vheight);                                                                  

  var newtimestamp = element.Timestamp;                                                                                    
  if( oldtimestamp != newtimestamp ) {                                                                                     
        console.log('ffmpeg  -i f1.vob  -ss 00:00:' + (element.Timestamp/1000) + '   -qmin 1 -q:v 1 -frames:v 1 ./pictures/frame' + element.Timestamp + '.png ');                                                                                     
     oldtimestamp = newtimestamp;                                                                                          
     sequence = 1;                                                                                                         
        }                                                                                                                  
  console.log('ffmpeg -i ./pictures/frame' + element.Timestamp + '.png -vf  "crop=' + size.Width + ':' + size.Height + ':' + size.Left + ':' + size.Top +  '"  ./faces/frame' + element.Timestamp + '' + sequence + '.png');                          
     sequence++;                                                                                                           
});
```

Used docker for the ffmpeg, zero installation, pick and run.

> docker run -it --rm --entrypoint='bash' -v ${PWD}:/tmp/workdir
>   jrottenberg/ffmpeg

The timestamp you need to divide by 1000 to convert milliseconds to seconds. added the #!/bin/sh manually.

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                  
ffmpeg  -i f1.vob  -ss 00:00:0   -qmin 1 -q:v 1 -frames:v 1 ./pictures/frame0.png                                          
ffmpeg -i ./pictures/frame0.png -vf  "crop=171:200:446:70"  ./faces/frame01.png                                            
ffmpeg -i ./pictures/frame0.png -vf  "crop=170:198:168:43"  ./faces/frame02.png                                            
ffmpeg -i ./pictures/frame0.png -vf  "crop=192:224:532:23"  ./faces/frame03.png                                            
ffmpeg -i ./pictures/frame0.png -vf  "crop=151:176:82:85"  ./faces/frame04.png                                             
ffmpeg  -i f1.vob  -ss 00:00:0.2   -qmin 1 -q:v 1 -frames:v 1 ./pictures/frame200.png                                      
ffmpeg -i ./pictures/frame200.png -vf  "crop=170:198:446:71"  ./faces/frame2001.png                                        
ffmpeg -i ./pictures/frame200.png -vf  "crop=174:203:167:43"  ./faces/frame2002.png                                        
ffmpeg -i ./pictures/frame200.png -vf  "crop=194:226:531:22"  ./faces/frame2003.png                                        
ffmpeg -i ./pictures/frame200.png -vf  "crop=152:176:81:86"  ./faces/frame2004.png                                         
ffmpeg  -i f1.vob  -ss 00:00:0.4   -qmin 1 -q:v 1 -frames:v 1 ./pictures/frame400.png                                      
ffmpeg -i ./pictures/frame400.png -vf  "crop=170:197:446:71"  ./faces/frame4001.png                                        
ffmpeg -i ./pictures/frame400.png -vf  "crop=174:203:167:43"  ./faces/frame4002.png                                        
ffmpeg -i ./pictures/frame400.png -vf  "crop=194:226:531:22"  ./faces/frame4003.png                                        
ffmpeg -i ./pictures/frame400.png -vf  "crop=152:176:81:86"  ./faces/frame4004.png                                         
ffmpeg  -i f1.vob  -ss 00:00:0.6   -qmin 1 -q:v 1 -frames:v 1 ./pictures/frame600.png
```

Copy output to S3:

aws s3 cp faces s3://outputbucket/faces/ --recursive

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

to your question, you can get the faces alone by cropping the sections of the face from the original image using the bounding boxes returned from aws rekognition. I have done with python

```
     widtho = 717 #width of the given image
     heighto = 562 #height of the given image
     counter = 0
     facecount = 1
     s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
     bucket = s3.Bucket('rek')
     if __name__ == "__main__":
     #Choosing the file in s3 bucket
         photo = 'sl.jpg'
         bucket = 'rek'
     #Intilization of rekognition and performing detect_faces 
     client = boto3.client('rekognition', region_name='eu-west-1')
     response = client.detect_faces(
     Image={'S3Object': {'Bucket': bucket, 'Name': photo}}, Attributes=['ALL'])
     print('Detected faces for ' + photo)
     print('The faces are detected and labled from left to right')
     for faceDetail in response['FaceDetails']:
         print('Face Detected= ', i)
         #To mark a bounding box of the image using coordinates
         print('Bounding Box')
         bboxlen = len(faceDetail['BoundingBox'])
         print(bboxlen)
         width = faceDetail['BoundingBox'].get('Width')
         height = faceDetail['BoundingBox'].get('Height')
         left = faceDetail['BoundingBox'].get('Left')
         top = faceDetail['BoundingBox'].get('Top')
         w = int(width * widtho)
         h = int(height * heighto)
         x = int(left * widtho)
         y = int(top * heighto)
         img2 = image_np[y:h, x:w]
         #now you can push the img2 which is one of the face in the single frame
```

Comment: All I have is the mp4 file and results from recognition. How do I get the frames from video and extract the images? Looks like your code extracts face from a image.

Comment: you have to create another script that  uses OpenCV to  read the  video frame at particular timestamps when faces detected then  crop the  faces of each frame  and stores in local or s3 from the face bounding box as per the above method

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If you got a script can you please share, that is my question is all about. Feed a video, extract faces and save in s3.

Comment: Exactly I don't have the code.... but you have to think smart, not all the frames in the video has faces in it ...if you wish to save money from aws rekognition do local opencv to detect faces in frame , if detected send the frame to s3 bucket ... then do rekognition in the images in the bucket,ensure to save images with relevant frame time name... such that while you return the coordinates for the particular frame, you can  do cv2.rectangle with the obtained coordinates for the detected frames in the video

Comment: Thank you. Converting video to images is a cumbersome process and takes longer time with read and writes. rekognition should be able to do it on the fly. Still did not have time to look at it. Will keep updated.